# Avoid postback in textchanged event without updatepanel c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, bootstrap-tags-input

How can I avoid postback in textchange event without using updatepanel.

When I use the updatepanel the css in my table is not working. I am using Bootstrap tags input in my table.

[View image without update panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU84a.png)

When I use the updatepanel the tag inputs is not working

[View image with update panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2PsG.png)

I am using `AutoPostBack="true"` so that the cdde behind would trigger.

Here are my codes:

Front end:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch"  style="border-radius:10px;padding:5px 5px" CssClass="textbox" Font-Size="24px" Width="100%" placeholder="Tell us about you DREAM HOUSE" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtSearch_TextChanged" ></asp:TextBox>
                   
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ServicePath="AutoComplete.asmx" ServiceMethod="SearchSubCategory" MinimumPrefixLength="1"
ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server"
CompletionInterval="0"
EnableCaching="false"
CompletionSetCount="10"
TargetControlID="txtSearch"
FirstRowSelected="false">
```

Code behind:

```
 protected void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (HiddenField1.Value == "")
                {
                    HiddenField1.Value = HiddenField1.Value + txtSearch.Text;
                }
                else
                {
                    HiddenField1.Value = HiddenField1.Value + "," + txtSearch.Text;
                }
                txtSearch.Text = "";
                Literal1.Text = "";
                DisplaySubCategory();
    
            }

 protected void DisplaySubCategory()
        {
            arr1 = HiddenField1.Value.Split(',');
            str.Append("<table id='tblsummary' class='displayresult'>");

           
                strsql = "select description from category where show_customerpage=1";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(strsql, conn);
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
                conn.Open();
                ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                dt = new DataTable();
                ad.Fill(dt);
                desccategory.DataSource = dt;
                desccategory.DataBind();
                conn.Close();
                for (i = 0; i < desccategory.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    str.Append("<tr>");
                    str.Append("<th>");
                    str.Append(desccategory.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text);
                    str.Append("</th>");
                    str.Append("</tr>");
                    for (k=0;k<arr1.Length;k++)
                    {
                    strsql = "select subcategory.subcat,description from subcategory inner join dbo.category on subcategory.cat_id = category.cat_id where subcategory.subcat='" + arr1[k] +"'";
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(strsql, conn);
                    conn.Open();
                    using(reader=cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (reader.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                HiddenField4.Value = reader["description"].ToString();
                                
                                if (HiddenField4.Value == desccategory.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text)
                                {
                                    if (HiddenField2.Value == "")
                                    {
                                        HiddenField2.Value = HiddenField2.Value + reader["subcat"].ToString();
                                       
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        HiddenField2.Value = HiddenField2.Value + "," + reader["subcat"].ToString();
                                       
                                    }
                                }
                        }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (desccategory.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text == "Others")
                            {
                                if (HiddenField2.Value == "")
                                {
                                    HiddenField2.Value = HiddenField2.Value + arr1[k];
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    HiddenField2.Value = HiddenField2.Value + "," + arr1[k];
                                }
                                
                            }
                            
                        }
                        
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                    }

                str.Append("<tr>");
                str.Append("<td>");
                str.Append("<input id='text1' class='bootstrap-tagsinput form-control' style='background: transparent;' data-role='tagsinput' type='text' value='" + HiddenField2.Value + "' />");
                str.Append("</td>");
                str.Append("<tr>");
                HiddenField2.Value = "";

            }

            
                str.Append("</table>");
            Literal1.Text = str.ToString();
        }
```

I am creating a dynamic table with bootstrap tag input inside.
All i need is to remove the postback so that the css bootstrap tag input will work
.
I hope someone has encountered this.

Need some help! Thanks!

Comment: Show us your code so that we can help you.

Comment: Ill edit my quesetion.

Comment: @SelimYıldız i have updated my question. i hope you can help

Comment: Why css is not working when you use UpdatePanel? I think you should solve this problem instead of avoiding postback event for textbox.

Comment: I also need to avoid the postback. Just population the tables in my posted image without postback. But my table is dynamically created from code behind so if I remove the `AutoPostBack="true"`, the code behind won't trigger

Comment: I also need to avoid the postback. Just population the tables in my posted image without postback. But my table is dynamically created from code behind so if I remove the `AutoPostBack="true"`, the code behind won't trigger